# Angular 10 Observable responds multiple times

Tags: angular, types, rxjs, observable, blob

I have a function in my Angular 10 app where I create a blob and upload a file. When I subscribe to that observable, it responds five times. I cannot figure out where or why?

```
uploadBacklogUploadFile(data, fileName: string) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
    this.backlogUploadService
      .uploadBacklogFile(blob, fileName, this.selectedJoin.id)
      .subscribe(        
        () => {  <-----this block of code will run 5 times
          this.uploadPercent = 100;
          this.dialogRef.close(true);
          this.openDialog();
          this.backlogUploaded.emit(true);
        },
        () => {
          this.uploadPercent = 0;
          this.snackBar.open('The backlog failed to be uploaded', null, {
            panelClass: 'snack-bar-error'
          });
        },
      );
  }
```

And my service

```
  public uploadBacklogFile(file: string | Blob, fileName: string, Id: number): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const requestView = new BacklogUploadRequestView(Id);
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('backlogUpload', new Blob([JSON.stringify(requestView)], { type: 'application/json' }), '');
    formData.append('file', file, fileName);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'application/json',
    });
    const url = this.remoteClientUtils.getThorUrl() + `${this.BACKLOG_UPLOAD_URL}`; 
    console.log("checkpoint") <------- this will only log once, so it must be nothing above?
    return this.httpClient.request(HttpMethods.POST, url, {
      body: formData,
      headers: headers,
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.remoteClientUtils.handleError<HttpEvent<any>>(null)));
  }
```

Comment: If you don't need to support the upload progress, just remove the `reportProgress: true` and `observe: 'events'` options, and it should be emitted once only.

Answer (score 1):

You try to track the progress of uploading, when you use `reportProgress` and `observe` (https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server), I think, you should delete these options

```
this.httpClient.request(HttpMethods.POST, url, {
   body: formData,
   headers: headers,
   reportProgress: true, //delete this
   observe: 'events'    // and delete this
})
```